order of references with biber
Among other references, I have to deal in my bibliography with two references, same year, same authors, but however i would like to point that there is chronological order between the two. Biber sort the two references by the title of the paper and unfortunately it provides the reverse order.  I tried to set sorting=nyt and to add SORTYEAR={2024-1} and SORTYEAR={2024-2} but that did not work. How could i do ?
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{testbib.bib}
@article {RG2024a,
  AUTHOR = {Durand, R. and Charles, G.},
  TITLE = {Note on a famous theorem},
  JOURNAL = {Foo},
  YEAR = {2024},
}


@article {RG2024b,
  AUTHOR = {Durand, R. and Charles, G.},
  TITLE = {Mysterious theorem},
  JOURNAL = {Bar},
  YEAR = {2024},
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
%
\usepackage[style=alphabetic]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{testbib.bib}

\begin{document} 
First there was \autocite{RG2024a}. Then came 
\autocite{RG2024b}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}

Thanks!

What do you mean "there is chronological order between the two"? In the original entry types what information demonstrates the chronological order?

Quick hack: use the sorttitle field to get the order you want
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{testbib.bib}
@article {RG2024a,
  AUTHOR = {Durand, R. and Charles, G.},
  TITLE = {Note on a famous theorem},
  JOURNAL = {Foo},
  YEAR = {2024},
  sorttitle={a},
}


@article {RG2024b,
  AUTHOR = {Durand, R. and Charles, G.},
  TITLE = {Mysterious theorem},
  JOURNAL = {Bar},
  YEAR = {2024},
  sorttitle={b},
}


\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
%
\usepackage[style=alphabetic]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{testbib.bib}

\begin{document} 
First there was \autocite{RG2024a}. Then came 
\autocite{RG2024b}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}



Thank you ! It is frustrating, it works perfectly on this minimal code but in my real document that does not work.

Try to use presort instead of sorttitle
